# mvc текст ошибок валидации

Tags: php, mvc

изучаю на практике патерн mvc, допустим, я создал маленький класс для валидации, в котором 2 метода на проверку логина и пароля, текст и функция вывода ошибок на страницу сайта будет хранится в этом же классе, а в контроллере для екшенов регистрации и входа, я буду вызывать статично нужный мне метод, который в случае не валидности данных будет выдавать ошибку я правильно поступаю?

и еще похожий вопрос, допустим я в контроллере вызываю екшен регистрации в нем вызывают модель и ее метод на проверку занят ли емейл, и если занят, будет ли правильно в моделе указать текст и сделать вывод ошибки на сайт, или в моделе нужно вернуть только true/false, а текст ошибки и вывод писать в контроллере, как правильно?

Comment: Текст ошибки должен генерироваться в VIEW. В данном случае модель не должна хранить такие тексты. По поводу первой вашей части, вызывать ли статично либо создавать экземпляр класса - по мне так статические методы не всегда удобно применять, у них есть минусы. По поводу модели, в целом (по мне) можно использовать 2 метода валидации логина и пароля если эта модель в целом для работы с юзерами.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, нет, не верно, с бизнес логикой должен работать контроллер, ничего промежуточного быть недолжно.

Второе верно, можно гинерировать boll, модель не должна отвечать за создания текста ошибок, и прочие.

Comment: т.е. как я понял вывод ошибок и текст должен быть в контроллере, а если я к примеру буду метод валидации на проверку логина использовать в разных контроллерах, и текст ошибки будет везде одинаковый, мне что его тупо копировать из контроллера в контроллер?

Comment: Тогда методы валидация, и вывода шаблоных ошибок, поместите в базовый контролёр, и просто используйте его при наследовании.