# php mvc где хранить текст ошибок

Tags: php, mvc

Изучаю MVC столкнулся с проблемой дублирования текста ошибок. Вот мой `UserController`, `User` - это модель контролера `UserController`

```
class UserController
{
    public function actionRegister()
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (!User::checkEmail($email)) {
            $errors[] = 'Неправильный email';
        }

        if (!User::checkPassword($password)) {
            $errors[] = 'Пароль не должен быть короче 6-ти символов';
        }
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (!User::checkEmail($email)) {
            $errors[] = 'Неправильный email';
        }

        if (!User::checkPassword($password)) {
            $errors[] = 'Пароль не должен быть короче 6-ти символов';
        }
    }
}
```

будет ли правильно перенести сообщения с ошибками в модель, что бы не дублировать их каждый раз в контроллере? Или что посоветуете сделать?

Comment: Я думаю, это зависит от предпочтений и того, что за сайт вы делаете. Если сайт большой или может разрастись, то тогда не помешает следовать принципу DRY (Don't repeat yourself) и избегать дублирования. На вашем месте я бы перенес сообщения об ошибках в какой-нибудь массив с типовыми ошибками типа `$errMessages`. Но решать все равно вам.

Comment: а если их прямо в моделе отдавать вместо true/false ? Это будет правильно?

Comment: Коротко: Да (я думаю); Длинно: MVC как таковой не говорит кто должен проверять данные на правильность: модель или контроллер. Так что сами решайте, как Вам удобнее.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, конечно удобней в моделе, хотелось бы еще услышать мнения!

Comment: [Вот еще посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719601/mvc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)